# How can I add a confirmation alert on radio button selection?

Tags: radio-button, alert, confirmation

At the end of a form I have the code below which asks a user to select yes or no radio buttons. Often, the wrong option is selected and I want to limit this by adding a 'Are you sure' confirmation statement/alert. The options should remain the same, just a further yes/no I guess.

```
<td class="t1_head">Keep with Tier 3?</td>
<td class="t1">
  <input type="radio" name="open" value="Yes" checked> Yes &nbsp; 
  <input type="radio" name="open" value="No"> No &nbsp; 
  <i>(This overrides the above scheduling)</i>
</td>
```

Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to do this with javascript as the user clicks? If so you can either use some simple vanilla js or if you have it loaded use jQuery. Are you happy with a standard alert or would you like a bespoke box etc?

Comment: Hi Simon, this is what we have at present:                                       <td class="t1_head">Keep with Tier 3?</td>
  <td class="t1"><input type="radio" name="open" value="Yes" checked> Yes &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="open" value="No"> No &nbsp; <i>(This overrides the above scheduling)</i></td>

Comment: Just looking for a standard alert to say 'Are you sure' with the yes or no they have selected. and then either proceed or allow them to change radio button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using javascript

```
<script>
  // get yes button
  var yes = document.getElementById('YesID');

  // get no button
  var no = document.getElementById('NoID);

  // when yes is clicked
  yes.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // warn
    var result = warn();

    // if selected no, switch button
    if (!result) no.checked = true;
  });

  // when no is clicked
  no.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // warn
    var result = warn();

    // if selected no, switch button
    if (!result) yes.checked = true;
  });

  function warn() {
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to select this ?');
  }
</script>
```

Note : Replace the 'YesID' and 'NoID' with the correct id of the two radio buttons.

Comment: Many thanks, I will try this on Monday and let you know.